# How can I convert the SuperStructure.cmof of the UML into c# classes

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I'm trying to parse `*.xmi` files exported from `Enterprise Architect`, so I've chosen the approach of converting the `xmi` schema files into c# classes, the problem is that the `xmi` schema depends on the `superstructure.cmof` of the UML.

I've tried the utility function `xsd.exe` and it worked for the `XMI.xsd` file only, but it didn't work on the `superstructure.cmof` file.

Is there a way to convert the `superstructure.cmof` into c# classes?

Comment: **(0)** Welcome to StackOverflow **(1)** Quick Google search for "C# uml mof manipulation library" pointed me to a C# open source library where the thing (XMI schema to C# classes) seems to be already done.. **(2)** see http://sourceforge.net/p/numl/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/numl/ **(3)** I don't know if and how [Rodolfo Campero](http://sourceforge.net/u/rodolfocampero/profile/) converted the superstructure.cmof, but points (1),(2),(3) should help you to get started. I would personally spend few days on (1)